# operator '+' cannot be applied to java.lang.string

Tags: java, android

```
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error Loading ", + nextImageName, e);
}
```

Above code generates an error message:

```
"operator '+' cannot be applied to java.lang.string"
```

I am a self-learner and I searched for this error message in other places before posting here. I have looked at the line but cannot make sense of the error message, and I am stumped.

Comment: What do you expect the `+` to do there? why?

Comment: You have a comma outside the string, you cant start an argument with +

Comment: @user2267921: Yes you can. `foo("bar", +3)` is valid, for instance. :-) But the unary `+` cannot be applied to a string.

Answer (score 8):

Just write it like this:

```
Log.e(TAG, "Error Loading " + nextImageName, e);
```

Answer (score 5):

> operator '+' cannot be applied to java.lang.string

The reason you're seeing that error is that because of the comma here:

```
Log.e(TAG, "Error Loading ", + nextImageName,e);
// ------------------------^
```

...the `+` is starting a new expression, and so it's the [*unary* `+` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3) (a "unary" operator is an operator that takes only one operand), not the binary `+` operator (an operator that takes *two* operands), which in that context would be the [string concatenation operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1). The unary `+` operator is a counterpart to the rather-more-well-known unary `-` which negates a number, and like the `-` can only be used with types that can be promoted to numeric values.

The *binary* `+` can be applied to strings, but the unary `+` cannot.

Removing the comma makes it a binary `+` (string concatenation, in this case), which works.

Comment: @MuhammadEbad: Don't know. The error message isn't hyper-obvious, for instance (e.g., it's not one of those errors where the answer to the question is right there in the error message).

Comment: @MuhammadEbad If I had to guess I'd say it's because a certain level of "trying on your own" is expected here (whether you agree or not). Your question *resembled* "Ah! Error! Dump it on SO!" Regardless of the confusing error, a close look at the line for other errors is expected. Even if you *did* stare at it a while, and were legitimately stumped, it's usually a good idea to *say* that in questions here. As silly as it seems, many of the active users here have been, let's say, "traumatized", by repeated exposure to *actual* bad questions (which may not include yours). :)

Comment: @JasonC: *"let's say, "traumatized", by repeated exposure to actual bad questions"* I love it. :-)